# Old contacts show on my partner's phone despite erasing it on mine

Tags: contacts, sync, delete

My partner  tells me that number and names of contact I have deleted keep appearing as soon as I log on.
I do NOT have these numbers and names in my contacts.
How it is so? How can I fix that? 
Do I need to delete my account?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have deleted your contacts on your phone, and not on your Gmail account.

Log on to your Gmail account at google.com, click the button at the top right, and then click more, then contacts.

From there you should be able to delete all of the contacts you no longer wish to have. Afterwards restart any devices, and refresh/sync any affected accounts. It might take a day (guessing) before the change is represented on every device.